# Accidently Uninstalled Built-in Bluetooth Adapter from HP Laptop Reinstalling

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I accidentally uninstalled (Device Manager -> Uninstall Bluetooth Adapter) the built-in Bluetooth Adapter, Broadcom 43142 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter, from a HP Stream (2015 model year) laptop (running Windows 10) because it was not picking up a pair of Bluetooth headphone I have. Now, I don't see a Bluetooth device in Device Manager (even when I opt to show hidden devices.) I am wondering whether there's a way to reinstall the uninstalled built-in adapter. I checked online and most articles come up saying I need to reinstall Windows 10.

On a side note, before uninstalling the built-in adapter, it failed multiple times to recognize a pair of Bluetooth headphones while my iphone successfully did. Does that mean the built-in adapter was malfunctioning? I've never paired anything via Bluetooth on this laptop before and this was the firs time I was using it.

Comment: Go to the HP Support site for your particular model and download the Bluetooth driver for your machine. Then install it. They should have the driver.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Could you tell me how to do that? Because what I download is a .cab file which gets extracted. The guides say I need to go to the device, install driver and point to the extract of the cab archive. But since I don't have the BT device listed I am unable to do that.

Comment: Got it. The uninstalled adapter was listed under other devices and updated the driver. Thank you. But, I still can't connect my headphones by going to Add Bluetooth Device. Do you think the Bluetooth adapter is malfunctioning?

Comment: Look for a folder on C drive call SWSetup, the driver software may be in a folder in there.

Comment: Go to Device Manager, find Bluetooth, right click and Update (not uninstall). Then go to Devices and Printers, and delete the Headphone device(s).  Restart.  Now pair up the Headphones again.

Comment: Thanks @John, I didn't have the BT headphones paired, when I go to Add a new BT device and start scanning for devices, it fails to find the device. I guess the BT adapter is faulty.

Comment: That is a likely possibility.